# Dynamic image style?

Tags: 7, media

I need to display profile image, but less blurred each day 
for example:

- day 1 : blur 30
- day 2 : blur 20
- day 3 : blur 10

Image style seems not to be dynamic. And I didn't find a way to do this.

Have you an idea I could explore?

Comment: use mytheme_preprocess_field hook along with accessing user's days on your site and having image_styles. I will recommend to go for CSS/JS rather than loading backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create the different image styles within the admin UI and then use a hook in your theme to override beased on your logic

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
    // ... add your logic 
    $variables['style_name'] == 'image_style_machine_name';
}
```

OR another possibility could be

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image_style(&$variables) {
    // ... add your logic 
    $variables['style_name'] = 'image_style_machine_name';  
}
```

**NOTE:** both are untested

Comment: Hi! It looks simply : I'll test that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, implemementing a proprocess function linked to block generation was too difficult for me actually.

I've found another solution (I think it's not the best, but it works) :

```
        case 'mymodule_block':
$block['content'] = theme('image_style',
          array(
            'style_name' => 'flou_80',
            'path' => $photo_profile,
            'attributes' => array('style' => 'border:1px solid #aaa;')
            )
          );
```